# Counting sequences using Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Count the number of sequences $a_{1},...,a_{2015}$ such that:

$a_{i}\in \{-1,1\}$, and $\sum _{i=1} ^ {2015} a_{i}=7$, and $\sum _{i=1} ^{j} a_i >0$ for every $1\leq j\leq 2015$

I assume we have to use Catalan numbers somehow.

It's clear that the number of $1$'s = number of $-1$'s $+7$. From the third condition it's also clear that the sequence must start with $1$. Beyond that, I can't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: This strikes me as a Dyck path that ends 7 above it's "ground level" if that makes sense

Comment: basically it's like a balanced sequence (same number of positive and negative elements) after we choose where to put some $7$ ones. So maybe it's (2015 choose 7) $\cdot C_{2008}$ ?

Comment: Or maybe (2015 choose 7)$\cdot C_{1004}$

Comment: I've deleted my answer because of what you pointed out and because I don't have the time right now to edit it correctly. Perhaps I'll leave it for someone else to attempt

Comment: In principle though you should be able to work it out using Dyck paths, balls in bins and a bit of intuition

Answer (score 2):

Use the reflection principle. Clearly $a_1 = 1$, so we can instead count the number of paths $a_1,\ldots,a_{2014}$ which sum to $6$ whose partial sums are always non-negative. Using the [reflection principle](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math47aF08/M47F08Note09b5.pdf), we find that the number of these paths is
$$
\binom{2014}{1010} - \binom{2014}{1003}.
$$
More generally, if $2015$ is replaced by $n+1$ and $7$ is replaced by $t+1$, the answer is
$$
\binom{n}{(n+t)/2} - \binom{n}{(n-t)/2-1} = \\
\binom{n}{(n+t)/2} - \binom{n}{(n+t)/2+1} = \\
\binom{n}{(n+t)/2} \left(1 - \frac{(n-t)/2}{(n+t)/2+1} \right) = \\
\frac{t+1}{(n+t)/2+1} \binom{n}{(n+t)/2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using your idea of "a balanced sequence and a choice of where to put seven 1s" we get the following: $$\sum_{i_1 + \cdots + i_7 = 1004} C_{i_1} \cdots C_{i_6}$$

where $i_1,\dotsc,i_6 \geq 0$ (there are six of them because we are forced to put the first one in position one, as you noted).  That's a sum over $997 \choose 5$ terms though.